# empty array on gulpjs watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

i am a nodejs newbie
i need to watch files changes on two subdirectories, when any change occur i need to update a service worker

all works fine, but why lista array is empty?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var path = require('path'); 
var fs = require('fs');

root = '/var/www/website.it';
dest = root + '/var/cache/misc/assets/'

var dests = [dest + 'js/tygh/*.js', dest + 'design/themes/responsive/css/*.css'];

gulp.task('default', function(){
    watch(dests, function () {

        var lista = [];     

        dests.forEach(function(dirname){
            dirname = path.dirname(dirname);
            fs.readdir(dirname, (err, files) => {
                files.forEach(file => {
                    lista.push(dirname + '/' + file);
                });
            });
            console.log(lista); // here print list of files
        });

        console.log(lista);  // here print empty array []
    });
});
```

Comment: You are using the asynchronous version fs.readdir() so when you get to the outer console.log(lista) lista is still empty.  You can fix this by using fs.readdirSync() instead.

Comment: ok thanks problem solved